# Changing permission on multiple files within bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, array

I am trying to write a script to change the permissions of a number of other scripts, in multiple locations, to be executable. I've searched all over and can't seem to get the syntax correct. It is only changing the permissions on the first file in the list. I'm sure it's very simple. I'm just very new to this. Thank you for your help.

```
files=(/file/location/one/script1.sh /file/location/two/script2.sh /file/location/three/scriipt3.sh)

chmod +x $files
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `files` variable is an array and `$files` expands to the first element as you have noticed.  To execute `chmod` on all elements of the array, use

```
chmod +x "${files[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You defined an array, so you can loop through it:

```
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
  chmod +x "$file"
done
```

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak You are right, but my answer isn't technically wrong, and I think, opens the possibility to more complicated code that `chmod +x "${files[@]}"` can't perform.

Comment: It is already more complicated code. However it does the same as @Freddy's